# Jquery full calendar, refresh events not working?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, calendar

I have problem with my calendar. When I move events to another date, database performs update , but the events return on starting position..
What's wrong?

pls look

https://gyazo.com/5122a54317aba149d7315ff7e9e75e00

```
    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ path('update') }}",
                        data: {
                            Eventid:event.id,
                            Start:event.start.format(),
                            End:event.end.format()
                        },
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.status != 'success')
                                revertFunc();
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ); //should refresh events


                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            revertFunc();
                            alert('Error processing your request: ' + e.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
```

and controller

```
 public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $idEvent=$request->get('Eventid');
    $Start=$request->get('Start');
    $Stop=$request->get('End');
    $events= $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')->find($idEvent);
    $events->setStart($Start);
    $events->setEnd($Stop);
    $em->flush();

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $json = json_encode([
            'id' => $events->getId()

        ]);

        return new Response($json);
    }
}
```